# Two div elements in the same line

Tags: html, css, datatables-1.10

I am trying to align two `<div>` tags i the same and I have trying it with `inline-block` but the elements are not showing up on the same line. Below screenshot shows how it looks  like. I am using `DataTables` so I have a top class.

[image]

html

```
<div class="countFieldCell">
    <c:if test="${fn:length(intgList) > 0}">Total: ${fn:length(intgList)}</c:if>
    <c:if test="${fn:length(intgList) == 0}">No Data found..</c:if> 
</div>
<div class="outerCountSection">
<table id="esignTable" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell">Line of Business</th>
            <th align="center" width="14%" class="fieldLabelCell">Insured</th>
            <th align="center" width="15%" class="fieldLabelCell">Customer<br>Phone</th>
            <th align="center" width="16%" class="fieldLabelCell">Policy #</th>
            <th align="center" width="19%" class="fieldLabelCell">E-Sign<br>Created Date</th>
            <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell">Customer<br>Email</th>
            <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell" style="text-align: left"># of E-Sign Documents</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

CSS

```
.dataFieldCell {
  font: normal 10px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 0px;
```

}

```
.top {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-right: 31%;
}

.outerCountSection {
   background: #EAEAEA;
   font: normal 11px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   height: 15%; 
   padding-top: 0.25%; 
   padding-bottom: 0.15%;
}
```

Comment: which two div you want to be on same line?

Comment: countFieldCell which shows the total number and the outerCountSection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the css `width` property with `float` attribute. Use `padding-top` to maintain it on same row.

```css
.countFieldCell{
width:10%;
float:right;
text-align:right;
padding-top:10px;
}
.outerCountSection{
width:90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="countFieldCell">
  <c:if test="${fn:length(intgList) > 0}">Total: 1</c:if>
</div>
<div class="outerCountSection">
  <table id="esignTable" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell">Line of Business</th>
        <th align="center" width="14%" class="fieldLabelCell">Insured</th>
        <th align="center" width="15%" class="fieldLabelCell">Customer<br>Phone</th>
        <th align="center" width="16%" class="fieldLabelCell">Policy #</th>
        <th align="center" width="19%" class="fieldLabelCell">E-Sign<br>Created Date</th>
        <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell">Customer<br>Email</th>
        <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell" style="text-align: left"># of E-Sign Documents</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try `<span>` (display: inline) it will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

```
.countFieldCell{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work Peter. Could it because of the outerCountSection?

Comment: outerCountSection has to be "display: block" and the width must be set to auto.

Comment: Where is the class .top used?